# Base64 key - Android Play Store apk publish

Tags: java, libgdx, google-play, google-play-services

I am aware that the Base64 key is only needed for paid apps/purchases, but I have several games I'm about to publish and I wanted to charge for some of them.

It says this key file (which is just a long string, as far as I know) needs to go "inside my binary". They don't specify any filename, filetype, location or anything.

Where do I put this key and also what would I call the file?

Thanks

P.S. I got this straight from inside the Google Developers Console:

> Your license key for this application 
>   Base64-encoded RSA public key to include in your binary. Please remove any spaces. 
>   MIIBIjANB******************************************************cR2fJF29eBjbcnAc**************************xlggOQLxZ2T6ohUcEhgdh

Comment: @Super MeagaBroBro what do mean by charge for some of them  ? Are you talking about IAP  ?

Comment: or you want to publish Paid App instead of free ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talking about IAP then you can use [gdx-pay](https://github.com/libgdx/gdx-pay)

gdx-pay is cross-platform API for InApp purchasing. Add dependency in your gradle and refresh.

Artifacts are available in Maven Central repository.

Comment: thanks Abhishek.  i am basically at the stage of release now :D thanks again for you massive hel. LOL I took about 3 days to create the 3 games (including assets) from scratch! It took me longer than that to intergrate Google Play into just ONE of the, :S Oh well im there now and hopefully will find it smoother when doing my next one. Once my game is up ill post a link to android store if you can download and try it out that would be amazing haha :) it s totally free without ads etc and its called Flappy Turds :)) ill post link later its a fun game

Comment: Thanks, I just thought this might have been needed just to appear on Play Store. I won't be handling in-app purchased just yet, but once I do this here is important info I wasnt aware of cheers.